# Correct use of parents scope properties

Tags: angularjs, scope, parent, controllers, partials

I'm really new on AngularJS and i don't know the best practices so here is my question.

What is the recommended use of parents controllers properties? Should I use different alias trough the entire webapp or there is another way to use vars and methods of a parent controller?

I'm using partials html and seems it can be confusing see userCtrl.doSomething when the partial has no declaration of userCtrl (because its declared on a partial thats includes this one).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: as much as possible, get into the habit of thinking of each "partial" as it's own independent program.  You can use input parameters to Directives, or Shared services, or Events to communicate between each individual partial.  You should design partials in such a way that they could function if they were the only thing rendered on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should avoid to use $parent** and scope variables that are not declared in your controller.

**Why ?** Because if you use it, your controller will be directly dependent to where you instantiated it (`ng-controller`). So you won't respect the MVC pattern. Your controllers should not be dependent on the View.

Your controller should not know what are his parents. Because you can do it doesn't means that you should to it.

**To share data between controllers, use Services** instead. That's easier and cleaner.

Comment: Ok, I can share the data whit services but what if I need to invoke a method of the parent controller's scope?

Comment: **Services can store functions too**. And if you really need to have this method on a controller (if this method can't be in a singleton (service) and is really dependant of the instance of the controller), you can use **angular events**. But services should always be the first thing you have in mind : the angular dependency injection is a very good tool.

Comment: I think I understand. For example, for control the User logged in, I should have a service with all that I need and inject it in all controllers I need it and in the controllers expose to the view doing something like:     $scope.user = UserService.getUser();